# SharePoint Online - list all sites in collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, site

How do I list all sites in my site collection in SharePoint Online?

I am not trying to view the 'Site Hierarchy' - this lists subsites of the site I'm viewing at the time, not all sites in the collection.  When I go to my 'main' site (https://companyname.sharepoint.com/), I can see subsites of that site, but not all sites that have been created by clicking on the 'Sharepoint' at the top of the screen and then 'Create Site'.  These appear as https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName.

I am not trying to view 'Sites and Workspaces' - this also only lists the subsites of the current site, not all sites created as described above.

I'd prefer something that didn't involve PowerShell - as that involves me booting a Windows system to use it.

Are these actually all different site collections?  If so, how do I get to the admin centres for them?  The SharePoint admin centre linked from the Office365 admin portal only shows four site collections:

- https://companyname.sharepoint.com/
- https://companyname.sharepoint.com/portals/hub
- https://companyname.sharepoint.com/search
- https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/

Comment: Is that do you want to retrieve all the site collections in you tenant? The site collections that you have mentioned in your question seems that they are from your Office 365 tenant.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni: I'm sorry, I don't really know what you mean.  What is my "tenant"?

Comment: Tenant means the Admin Center in SharePoint Online. Unlike there is farm, thats represents the web applications in SharePoint Onpremises. Means you have a Central Administration in SHarePoint Onpremise that represent all of your web applications in farm.

Comment: Do you want to list all the site collections those mentioned in the question in one of the list of your site https://companyname.sharepoint.com/.

Comment: As it says in the first line of the question, this is about SharePoint Online.

Comment: The four items you listed above are each site collections within your tenant (the companyname.sharepoint.com).  There are many additional flavors of site collections - project, publishing, collaboration, etc.  Each of those collections would contain the individual sites and sub-sites.  
There is one SP Online Admin Center. You would manage each of those site collections from the root/landing page of those collections.  Right now there is not a pretty way to display cross-collection links, but there are changes on the roadmap that should accommodate this quicky without too much configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The sites created through 'Create Site' are modern site collection/Office 365 Groups (in fact any new sites created now are modern by default) and you cannot see/manage these in the SharePoint Admin.  Microsoft will be releasing the new SharePoint Admin Centre where you will also see all the modern site collections.  I think you can sign-up for preview, if your SharePoint Admin Centre still doesn't show a link 'Try the new SharePoint admin center'

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Introducing-the-new-SharePoint-Admin-Center/ba-p/70294

The membership for these sites are control/managed through exchange admin center.

If you want all a list of all site collections (including modern ones), you can use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) or PowerShell.